# How does a server detect a request made with the fetch API?

Tags: json, http, exception, fetch-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application, which handles requests from my web site made with the fetch API.
When an exception occurred in my controller, I use my custom "OnException" method, overriden from System.Web.Mvc.Controller, to send a result in JSON, containing data about the error. I do this because I don't want to send the default HTML error page.
In this method, which is global for all controllers, I need to check if the request has been performed with the fetch API (if not, I don't do anything).

How can I do this ?

- Should I add a custom http header to my requests ?
- Should I add a specific parameter in all my requests ?
- Do I have a totally wrong approach ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either of a specific header or a specific parameter would work; the "clean" approach would probably be to set the "Accept:" header in the fetch-sent request to "application/json", signalling that the said request is looking for a JSON response, and use that on the server-side to determine whether to send JSON or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think Accept Header does not help for the all scenarios. If you request HTML and you have a layout system and want to disable it for async request you will need a different approach.

Using a custom flag header is a more guarantied approach I think.