# From server, how recognize javascript fetch() call was made (asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fetch-api

This is not quite a duplicate; the answer provided below is identical to a comment in the proposed duplicate answer.

From inside an asp.net controller action, I'm interested in knowing if the call was made by a javascript fetch() call. Is there any part of the Request object that I can interrogate to discover this?

For example, if I'm interested in knowing if the caller is a javascript $.ajax call, on the server-side I can call this method:

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest();
```

and if it returns true I know that the call was something like this:

```
       $.ajax({
        url: '/MyDomain/MyControllerAction',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            doSomething(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, ex) {
            doSomethingElse(XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, ex);
    });
```

Is there something like Request.IsAjaxRequest() I can call or interrogate to discover if the caller was a javascript fetch(), eg a call like this:

```
fetch('/MyDomain/MyControllerAction')
       .then(function (data) {
          if(data.ok){
            return data.json();
           }
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            doSomething(data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            doSomethingElseAgain(error);
        });
```

Comment: Do you want to treat `fetch` differently from `$.ajax`? Or do you want them to behave the same on the server?

Comment: I would expect `IsAjaxRequest` to have the same behavior, is that not the case?  Or are you trying to differentiate between `$.ajax()` and `fetch()` as well?  Why do you need to know this anyway?

Comment: IsAjaxRequest() does not return true for a fetch() request, that is why I posted the question.  As far as "why", I need to know so that I know how to handle errors.  I originally asked the question this way, but I realized I was including far too much information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048830/how-recognize-javascript-fetch-inside-handleerrorattribute-onexception

Comment: You mean like `app.get('/MyDomain/MyControllerAction', function(req, res) {` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend IsAjaxRequest() to include fetch api requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353074/extend-isajaxrequest-to-include-fetch-api-requests)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a server detect a request made with the fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996569/how-does-a-server-detect-a-request-made-with-the-fetch-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523844/1715579), `IsAjaxRequest` checks a specific HTTP header that's set by `$.ajax`. To make `IsAjaxRequest` return true for `fetch`set this header when you make your request, like this:

```
fetch('/MyDomain/MyControllerAction', { headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' } })
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for a full list of `fetch` options.